# CreateDataFrame with F#

Tags: c#, apache-spark, f#, .net-spark

I'm trying to create a simple Spark DataFrame with F# as it is used in [Spark.Net test](https://github.com/dotnet/spark/blob/master/src/csharp/Microsoft.Spark.E2ETest/IpcTests/Sql/SparkSessionTests.cs#L77)

```
let schema =
    StructType (
        [|
            StructField("Name", new StringType())
            StructField("Age", new IntegerType())
            StructField("Date", new DateType())
        |] )

let rows: obj[][] =
    [|
        [| "Alice"; 20; new Date(2020, 1, 1) |]
    |]

session.CreateDataFrame(rows |> Array.map GenericRow, schema).Show(10, 0, false)
```

eventually, this code fails (as exactly the same code using .NET collections)

```
JVM method execution failed: Nonstatic method 'createDataFrame' failed for class '7' when called with 2 arguments ([Index=1, Type=GenericRow[], Value=Microsoft.Spark.Sql.GenericRow[]], [Index=2, Type=JvmObjectReference, Value=8], )
```

Comment: Make sure that you use .NET for Spark v0.8 or later since the CreateDataFrame version has been added in v0.8

Answer (score 1):

The above runs well for me

```
+-----+---+----------+
|Name |Age|Date      |
+-----+---+----------+
|Alice|20 |2020-01-01|
+-----+---+----------+
```

- Please check you're using *Spark < 2.4.5*   I did the test with *2.4.1*
- *Java > 1.8*
- Also check you are providing all parameters

*$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner --master local bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/microsoft-spark-2.4.x-0.11.0.jar dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/yourLibrary.dll*